# failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'

Tags: android, gradle, target

[image]

I have updated android studio with latest version and then after googling I also updated Android SDK with API 18 but still it gives the same error.

Comment: Change  Grandle.build file from 18 to 17.may work

Comment: Gradle actually looks like this.... compileSdkVersion 22.... minSdkVersion 10.....targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: ok sorry then make it to 21

Comment: It worked perfectly fine but do i have to change targetSdkVersion as well ? and dependencies are based on 22 SDk whicg gives error now...

Comment: ok now try with 22 hope it work

Comment: if not work change the compileSdkVersion 21 only let the targetSdkVersion 22 be like this

Comment: Nope it is giving the same error if i change it to 22. I just kept the same... Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just click on the link written in the error:

> Open Android SDK Manager

and it will show you the dialogs that will help you to install the required sdk for your project.

Comment: Just installing an older SDK version is not the real solution! The real solution is to go through all of your gradle config files and upgrade the *version settings to your latest installed one, e.g. `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: I'd already installed version 22 using the sdk manager & still no luck (e.g. clicking on the link didn't do anything).  So I closed, and then re-opened android studio & that worked.

Comment: @BenMarten upgrading to the latest sdk may not help sometimes. One of projects i imported was using some `Apache Http` classes which was existed in sdk v19 and deprecated in >21.  So let the project install the required sdk, then if needed you can upgrade it.

Comment: Thank you @BenMarten i already got them, but since i wanted to get the project working asap, i did used the solution that i have posted, then i searched on google for the alternatives of apache http classes.

Comment: On my mac, I installed the SDK from the link, then Gradle run after a complete restart of Android studio.

Answer (score 15):

Open the **`Android SDK Manager`** and Update with latest :

1. **Android SDK Tools**
2. **Android SDK Build Tools**

Then **Sync ,Re-Build and Restart Your Project**
Demo Code for **`build.gradle`**

```
   compileSdkVersion 21 // Now 23
   buildToolsVersion '21.1.2' //Now 23.0.1

   defaultConfig
    {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19  
     }
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: So you're suggesting to change it to 23, in this example, assuming that's the latest?

Answer (score 5):

Okay you must try this guys it works for me:

1. Open SDK Manager and Install SDK build tools 22.0.1
2. Sync gradle That'all

Comment: No, just installing an older SDK version is not the real solution, as commented elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I modified **build.gradle compileSdkVersion to 23 from 22 and targetSdkVersion to 23 from 22.**

My API level was 23. I had to update the API version to 23 as well.

I had to import my project from Eclipse to Android Studio. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. I updated android studio build tools and my project didn't find "android-22".  I looked in android sdk manager and it was installed.

To fix this issue I uninstalled  "android-22" and installed again.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Cordova project, which created with latest android target android level 23. when i run it works. if i changed desire android target value from 23 to 22. and refresh the Gradle build from the Andoid Studio. now it's fail when i run it. i got the following build error.

project-android /CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.java
Error:(217, 22) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(String[],int)

I changed the target level in these files.

project.properties
AndroidManifest.xml

and inside CordovaLib folder.

project.properties

However, i also have another project which is using the android target level 22, whenever i run that project, it runs. Now my question is can we specify the desire android level at the time of creating the project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install API 18 from android sdk if not already installed, otherwise you can try "invalidate caches and restart" (Find: File->invalidate caches and restart).

Answer (score -1):

Change

**compileSdkVersion 18
 minSdkVersion 10
 targetSdkVersion 18**

in **build.gradle** in your app directory/module

Or Download Latest API Version

Comment: it gives a lot of compatibility error. Anyways thanks

Comment: :) Always Welcome.Please Build the  build.gradle file after Changing

Answer (score -1):

In sdk Manager download android 5.1.1, it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Open **project.properties** file and change the line with **target=android-22** to the desired value.
For example:

> target=android-19