# Git Repository not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-volley

Hey I am working on fecthing information from custom url address in my App.
Right now I am in the starting just finish the layouts of App 
and I install Git and created a volley folder and after importing the volley folder in project my program is showing that 
volley is registered as a git root but no git repository found....
Please guide me well how to resolve this problem..

thanks in Advnace

Comment: What is a volley module ?

Comment: i mean that volley file (folder) which we have to import as a module in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and Install Git from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. Open Git Bash by right-click on desktop
3. Type or paste:-  **$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley** in Git Bash
4. It will download ***volley*** folder from the internet .Default folder is in C:\Users\YOUR_PC_NAME\volley\

5.Import volley folder in your app by File->New->Import Module. Then select that volley folder click finish.

6.After importing volley folder into your project Android studio shows you a dialog box to configure the project. Click on configure and then select the line which you want to add then click the green add button on your right.

7. Open settings.gradle add or verify this is line- **include ':app', ':volley'**
8. Add or verify in dependencies **compile project(":volley")**

Comment: I cannot able to find volley folder.. its not in the Default directory.

Comment: Okay i find the Volley it was in Git folder. thank you

Comment: which software are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio.. Now i am trying to Authorize the web services by validating username password.. can you guid me how to do it using volley ?

Comment: If you are working on Android Studio, then after downloading volley folder, import volley folder in your app by File->New->New Module.

Comment: I modified my answer if error still exists then please tell me on more details

Comment: i want to ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624100/how-to-authorize-user-name-and-password-using-volley-lib-in-android-studio                                           can you tell me the answer of this

Comment: Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: 1. Open SDK Manager and Install SDK build tools 22.0.1 then Sync gradle

Comment: Still this Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':volley'.
   > failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22/33361724#33361724

Comment: when i remove the step 7 and 8 then the error gone but when I add it then It show this error again ..

Comment: Make sure that when importing volley module go to File->New->Import Module in Android Studio. Not by right click on project file.

Comment: press **Ctrl+Alt+S** then go to **Version Control** tab. Select the line under **Unregistered root** then click on **green ADD** button on the top-right corner.

Comment: there is an Other tool option but where is Unregistered root ?

Comment: Okay thank you I have add the unregistered file by clicking on Add button :)

Comment: if my answer is useful to you then please don't forget to click up button on my answer. Thanx