# Error :failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hash, compiler-errors

i saw a few posts like in the past - but none of the answers worked for me(like this one : [failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22)).
i got this probelm in my build.grandle

> failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'

**Screenshot of the problem:**

[image: screenshot]

**SDK manager:**

[image: sdk manager]

Answer (score 4):

In SDK Manager, install API: 22 SDK platform.

From your screenshot, you have to scroll down a bit more to reach (API 22).