# Parse SDK - Can't install (failed to find target with hash string 'android-22')

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to install `Parse SDK`. As their site says https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new i downloaded I extracted the `.zip` file and went to my project in Android Studio. As they say - File->Open-> `build.gradle` in the ParseStarterProject.
Then in the project i get these errors:
`Failed to sync Gradle project 'ParseStarterProject'`

`Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>`

I checked `StackOverFlow` all around for that error message and nothing helped. I got all the android sdk installed. As in here [failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22) I installed the Build tools.

Maybe i need to do something in `build.gradle`?

Any sugggesstions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downloading the zipp and import it in studio, you can directly use the dependencie:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
}
```

As shown here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-sdk-android

Comment: Well, that was easy. I been breaking my head in days to get this. Thanks. But how about the `<resources>
  <string name="parse_app_id">APPLICATION ID</string>
  <string name="parse_client_key">CLIENT KEY</string>
  ...
</resources>` do i need to add it too?

Comment: Yes you should add this

Comment: And leave it with the caps like in the example or i should have some values in there?

Comment: No you should replace it with your application Id and client id, if you have created your app in parse, it should be written here : https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new

Comment: For me it is written at the bottom in the Connect your app to Parse section

Comment: Else go to "Settings" and then "keys" and you will be able to see this parameters

Comment: Settings in `AndroidStudio`? because nothing is written there for me.

Comment: The setting of the Parse app in the Parse website :) But first you have to create an app in the parse website

Comment: Bu ti don't have a parse app on the website and they blocked the option to sign up :(

Comment: Oh if you cannot create an app on the website you will not be able to use it... They have block the signed up?! I think it is due to the fact that it will close in less than one year.. You are coming too late, you need to find an other solution, sorry