# Changing compileSdkVersion in Android Studio Is Giving an Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm testing an app in Android Studio for which I need to use `compileSdkVersion` lower than 23, but the current version of `compileSdkVersion` in Android Studio is 23 by default. I downloaded and installed `Android SDK build-tools` revision 22 and changed it in`build.gradle` as follows:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'
```

I've looked at a few similar questions but none helped me with this.

What should I do?

Comment: download android 5.1.1 sdk platform using sdk manager and resync your project

Comment: In what scenario do you ever need to compile with a lower SDK? You can always run code on a device within an API greater than or equal to the minimumSdk

Comment: I downloaded the source code of an app which belongs to a year ago or so. there are a couple of errors in the source code which are not run with compileSdkVersion 23

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22

Comment: @Mehran change your buildToolsVersion to 22.0.1 and sync your gradle.

Comment: @Mehran did you solve this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya not yet. I've done all the suggestions, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Mehran Okay .Any news ?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to the issue...
when I set the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` through file => project structure => (module) app, they were set in the build.gradle accordingly as below:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

And I thought that the dependencies section should be like this(i.e versions being the same as that of `buildToolsVersion`):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.0.1'
```

}

but after a lot of research I found out that there is no version as `22.0.1` for the `appcompat-v7`...
The version which I used for `appcompat-v7` and `design` which worked is `22.2.1`. So, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

### Note:

- You can set `compileSdkVersion 23`
- call `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`

Finally

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

You should update your **SDK Manager**

1. **Android SDK Tools**
2. **Android SDK Build Tools**

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Sync** Your Project .

> The Android SDK Manager separates the SDK tools, platforms, and other
>   components into packages for easy access and management. You can also
>   customize which sites the SDK Manager checks for new or updated SDK
>   packages and add-on tools. For example, you can configure the SDK
>   Manager to automatically check for updates and notify you when an
>   installed SDK Tools package is updated. When you receive such a
>   notification, you can then quickly decide whether to download the
>   changes.

Please read official guide line about **[SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/sdk-manager.html)** .

Hope this helps you .