# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' does not disappear while SDK 25 is installed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

In `Android Studio` I am facing the error:

```
Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: [path]
Possible cause: Build properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 25
```

No problem, I thought, so according to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22) I simply have installed the missing Android SDK: 
[image]

However I still get that issue. Even after rebuilding the project 
and restarting `Android Studio`

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Google libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    // Third party libraries
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.6.0'
    compile 'com.alexvasilkov:gesture-views:2.1.1'
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

**Note**: I have removed all installed Android SDK's and reinstalled them. Unfortunately that did not help.

What else can I do to fix the issue?

Here are Screenshots of my standalone SDK manager:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: post `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Launch the **standalone SDK manager** from your menu, in that you can view which components of that API level are installed. Some might still not be installed, select and update.

Comment: In the standalone SDK manger I have updated SDK Build tools and again I get the error message. Please see the screenshots I have added to my post