# Error:(10, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_355dfgbnsq5hubv8npxiakv03$_run_closure1@5c192b7f]

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My build.gradle afer updating it look like this. And it gives me the error.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
}
 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

earlier it looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

And that gave me this error -

```
  Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21' in: 
   /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk
  <a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

Don't know how to to get it fix. Please help just try to run app with components

Also checked all the possible solution. Possible duplicate

[failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22)
[Could not find method android() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250493/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below lines in `app` `build.gradle`, not in your project top level build.gradle.

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
}
```

In the left pane, select 'Project' view. Under ProjectName/app/ you will find a `build.gradle` file. Add the above lines in that file, and remove it from your top level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Happy to help. If it's working would you please upvote and mark it correct.

Comment: It takes atleast 5 minutes to do so. Also please upvote my question as well. So more people can see the question